# Bitbucket Server - How to get the Bitbucket Server instance

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

I'm new to Bitbucket Server.

Currently, I'm trying to configure a Jenkins job to build my repository, which is located in my personal space of Bitbucket Server (I'm not admin of BitBucket Server).
I followed the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-FugzVYJQU.

Inside Jenkins setting, I have put the URL to my company bitbucket server, personal access token, Credentials as per hint from Video... But the connection still fails.
My question is:

1 - Do I need the admin right of Bitbucket Server to setup these procedures or did I configure something wrong?

2 - If possible, how to get the Bitbucket Server instance when I don't have the
admin right of Bitbucket Server?

Sorry English not my native language.

Thank you for your help :)

[Jenkins Setting - Bitbucket Server instances entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv8rO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question 1,you don't need any admin access to bitbucket server to setup this procedure.If you are cloning from any repository, you need to make sure that the credential you are using, should have at least read access to particular repository.
For your second question, if you are setting up any jenkins job and Bitbucket team is different, you need to ask them for url or IP. Even you dont know ip, bitbucket server URL should be fine to connect with as long you are using correct credentials.

There can be multiple issue like firewall/no connectivity/security rules if jenkins is not able to connect though you are using correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - Do I need the admin right of Bitbucket Server to set up these
> procedures or did I configure something wrong?

You do not need admin rights of Bitbucket Server. You can add your own personal access token(PAT). Make sure your PAT has admin access.

> If possible, how to get the Bitbucket Server instance when I don't have the admin right of Bitbucket Server?

You have to configure your Bitbucket instance manually. Its explained from [here](https://youtu.be/0-FugzVYJQU?t=63) in the video.

If your repository is in your personal space, make sure while creating a job, the project name is `~<yourusername>`. Example `~jsmith`. Repository name will be populated using this.

Regards,
Bitbucket Server Developer